# How can I get names of the players who joined the game room?

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, tic-tac-toe

I am making a tic-tac-toe game using nodejs,socket.io and sql database to store the results. The problem is that I am unable to get the name of both the players that join the game room. How can I do that?

Comment: Without your code this questions is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your server has no notion of a "name" for a socket.io connection.  I can think of two ways to associate a name with a socket.io connection:

1. If the user is logged into your server via http and the server knows the name for that login, then you can access the login cookie from the socket.io connection and presumably use that to access the server-side session object and get the name that way.
2. You can have the client announce its name to the server by sending the server a socket.io message that tells it the name.  You server can then receive that message and set a custom property on the socket.io `socket` object to that name.  Note: this is not particularly secure since a client can announce any name it wants.  If that matters to you and you have a login name, then use the first option.